# AttributeError: 'Trainer' object has no attribute 'tuner'

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch-lightning

I try run code from site kaggle.
In program from  [this (kaggle: Time series with PyTorch)](https://www.kaggle.com/code/aneridalwadi/time-series-with-pytorch/comments) I get error on this code:

```
res = trainer.tuner.lr_find(
    tft,
    train_dataloaders=train_dataloader,
    val_dataloaders=val_dataloader,
    max_lr=10.0,
    min_lr=1e-6,
)
```

Text error:

```
AttributeError: 'Trainer' object has no attribute 'tuner'
```

I am aware of this error. It occurs because in version 2, there was a strong change in the library. Here is the link [link (google: lightning releases 2.0.0)](https://lightning.ai/pages/releases/2.0.0/). And this article provides the code for the previous version.

**But how should rewrite this code based on the new version of the library?**

Comment: take a look at this: https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/pull/16462. tl;dr do it this way:  
trainer = Trainer();
tuner = Tuner(trainer);
tuner.lr_find(...);
tuner.scale_batch_size(...);

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code, it works good:

```
trainer = L.Trainer(max_epochs=20)

tuner = L.pytorch.tuner.Tuner(trainer)

lr_find_results = tuner.lr_find(model,
                                train_dataloaders=dataloader,
                                min_lr=0.001,
                                max_lr=1.0,
                                early_stop_threshold=None)
```

Comment: Kindly leave an explanation of why your solution helped solve his problem, not just code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).